# Upsert ref documents when pushing to array in Express

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have a `Candidate` schema with an array of refs to an `Endorser` schema. Like so:

```
const CandidateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    endorsements: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Endorser'
    }]
});

const EndorserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
});
```

I receive `endorsements` in the form of an array of strings (i.e., the endorser's name). I want to iterate through that array and retrieve the `_id` of each from the `Endorser` model or upsert a new one if it doesn't exist. I then want to push those refs onto the existing `candidate` instance.

The following code works, but I really don't feel comfortable modifying the `candidate` instance in-memory. Having to do the promise resolution separately also seems weird.

```
    const endorsementPromises = endorsements.map(async endorser => {
        let endorserObj = await Endorser.findOneAndUpdate({name: endorser}, {name: endorser}, {upsert: true, new: true});
        return endorserObj._id;
    });
    const endorsementArray = await Promise.all(endorsementPromises);
    candidate.endorsements = candidate.endorsements.concat(endorsementArray);
    await candidate.save();
```

I have tried using [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/). However, this only returns an error and doesn't update the document.

```
Candidate.update(
        {id: candidate._id}, 
        {$push: {
            endorsements: {
                $each: endorsementArray
            }
        }}
    );
```

```
// the error
Error: {"n":0,"nModified":0,"ok":1}
```

I'm not sure why `$push` and `$each` aren't updating the document.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$addToSet` instead of `$push`.  Also, it seems like you should be matching on `_id` instead of `id` in your update.

Comment: Returns the same error and doesn't update the database.

Comment: Seems like you might have a typo in your query.  In your `update` are you supposed to be matching on `_id` instead of `id`?

Comment: Awoooops! That's it! Now I feel dumb.

Comment: Haha it's usually something small, glad I could help!